# Laravel validation for numbers with spaces

Tags: laravel-5.3

Laravel has a validation for some input types i have searched validation rule for numbers and it may contains some whitespaces or may not be. I have used validation rules of numeric and integer but its not allowing whitespaces.

And i have custom error message displayer with class. i need to show validator error message in that message but i got output error message as like below

[image]

How can i display error message of validator normally and my code is

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                    'header_logo'    => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,svg',
                    'contact_number' => 'numeric',
                    'contact_email'  => 'email',
                    'footer_logo'    => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,svg',
                    'enquiry_email'  => 'email',
                    'website'        => 'active_url', 
                    'vat'            => 'integer', 
                    'sale_mobile'    => 'numeric', 
                    'sale_email'     => 'email' 
                ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
         return back()->withInput()->with(['admin' => $validator->errors(), 'class' => 'danger']);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-regex
ex : 'regex:/[0-9 ]+/'

or https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-validation-rules